# How to maintain ConstraintLayout Guideline for right-to-left layouts?

Tags: android, layout, right-to-left, android-constraintlayout

The problem I've faced with is when I was trying to support right-to-left layout direction of my `ConstraintLayout` with `android.support.constraint.Guideline`, the attribute `layout_constraintGuide_begin` doesn't mirror guide in case of a right to left layout occurs. Is there any way to use the guideline for the right-to-left layouts?

Comment: Hi Serhii, have you found the solution? If yes, please share it. I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

To support guideline in right-to-left add this in values/dimens.xml

```
<resources>
 <item name="guide_percent" format="float" type="dimen">0.3</item>
</resources>
```

And add this value of `guide_percent` in values-ldrtl/dimens.xml file.

```
<resources>
     <item name="guide_percent" format="float" type="dimen">0.7</item>
</resources>
```

Use like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="@dimen/guide_percent" />
```